# Is there any way to reverse triangulation in Blender 2.91?

Tags: topology

I have a lowpoly character model that I've been working on/off for years and I'm finally reaching a point that's nearing completion. I'm experimenting with a new rigging method for the hip/thigh flex, but the mesh is becoming super jagged when twisting the leg, due to the leg topology's automatic triangulation. I can manually add in new edges to have a forced triangulation to go the other direction so that the leg twists more smoothly, but it makes selecting edge loops more tedious as a result. If I were to dissolve these manual triangulation-cuts, the mesh automatically goes back to the original triangulation.

Is there a way to change the direction of a polygon's triangulation via edit mode? Like say, changing it from [/] to [\] without having to manually add in a cut in between.
I know that there is a triangulation modifier, but I only need it for a specific section of the mesh, not the entire model.

Comment: Like this? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/rotate_edge.html

Comment: Are you stuck on 2.91?  The triangulation modifier is the rightest way to do this; everything gets triangulated eventually, so the fact that you only need some things triangulated doesn't matter, if you want to specify the triangulation it's fine to specify for all faces.  (You might need to get GN involved to join two differently triangulated meshes, then weld.)  But there have been improvements of the triangulation modifier in recent memory ("keep normals" functionality created, and then later made to work from base normals) and I'm not sure off the top of my head what 2.91 was like.

Comment: So far none of these suggestions are for what I am looking for. All of the polygons are quads, and I want to keep them as quads so that it's easier to edit the vertex group/weight paints with selected edge loops, as well as to better keep track of the topology when manipulating the rig. The automatic triangulation has everything become jagged when I rotate the limb in one direction, and I have to manually convert the quads to tris in order to better keep the smooth shape that I need when twisting this limb. Also, I need to stay in 2.9 because 3.0 patched out my modeling method.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer have 2.91 installed but it may be worth a check.

Go to Edit mode and select all the polygons you want to go from triangle to quad.
Then go to Face/Tris To Quads

[image]